# Database lock acquisition failure with hsqldb but erase .lck file not solved

Tags: java, hsqldb

Database lock acquisition failure running hsqldb :

```
start_hsqldb_server.bat

C:\Users\Patrick\Documents\PROFESSIONNEL\PEDAGOGIE\DATABASES\runserver.ShuttleWindows>java  -Xmx4096m  -cp .\hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.Server
[Server@41cf53f9]: Startup sequence initiated from main() method
[Server@41cf53f9]: Loaded properties from [C:\Users\Patrick\Documents\PROFESSIONNEL\PEDAGOGIE\DATABASES\runserver.ShuttleWindows\server.properties]
[Server@41cf53f9]: Initiating startup sequence...
[Server@41cf53f9]: Server socket opened successfully in 7 ms.
[Server@41cf53f9]: [Thread[HSQLDB Server @41cf53f9,5,main]]: Database [index=0, db=file:C:/Users/Patrick/Documents/PROFESSIONNEL/HSQLDB_DATA/typodoc/typodoc, alias=typodoc] did not open: org.hsqldb.HsqlException
: Database lock acquisition failure: lockFile: org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile@5ebdfb50[file =C:\Users\Patrick\Documents\PROFESSIONNEL\HSQLDB_DATA\typodoc\typodoc.lck, exists=false, locked=false, valid=false, ] method: openRAF reason: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Patrick\Documents\PROFESSIONNEL\HSQLDB_DATA\typodoc\typodoc.lck (Le fichier spÚcifiÚ est introuvable)
[Server@41cf53f9]: [Thread[HSQLDB Server @41cf53f9,5,main]]: Shutting down because there are no open databases
[Server@41cf53f9]: Initiating shutdown sequence...
[Server@41cf53f9]: Shutdown sequence completed in 0 ms.
[Server@41cf53f9]: 2022-03-11 18:16:27.098 SHUTDOWN : System.exit() is called next
```

I deleted **C:\Users\Patrick\Documents\PROFESSIONNEL\HSQLDB_DATA\typodoc\typodoc.lck** file but it not solve the problem... As I've got problems with my system files rights I suggest a properties right on folder of the database. I added total right for Me, Administrateurs and All users but it not solve. It look's like an other process is running the database but My MSDOS Script only lauch the server one time ... How to get more informations for this error ? How to audit system files rights for java process ?

Thank you for your help ...
Patrick

Comment: I add that I'm using Windows 10 and running CMD with admin rights not solve the problem... Also my database folder add total control for My user, Adminstrateurs and All Users...

Comment: Looks like windows access rights for the Java process. Try narrowing it down by using another folder.

Comment: Yes it is : I moved my database folder to USB key and it's running ! But I can't anderstand what to do into my C drive ? I don't know how to verify/edit the java rights on my database folder ?

Comment: Try running as administrator.